# How to extend inherited method instead of overriding it?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have two classes, `Alpha` and `Beta`, with `Beta` being an inherited class from `Alpha`. `Alpha` class has a method named `Roger()`. I would like `Beta` class to have the same `Roger` function, but I don't want to override all the code from `Alpha`. What I would like is to execute the `Roger` function from the `Alpha` class, and after that add some more code in `Beta` class.

Basically, I want to extend the `Roger` method, not completely replace it. Is this possible in C#?

For example:

`Alpha` class:

```
protected virtual void Roger()
{
  Console.Write("123");
}
```

`Beta` class:

```
protected something void Roger()
{
  Console.Write("456");
}
```

And `Beta.Roger()` would print "123456"

Comment: you can call `base.Roger();` and it would print 123 and then call` BetaClass.Roger();`and it would print 456

Comment: `extend` has no meaning here. What you ask is calling the base method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would still use the `override` keyword, but you would also call `base.Roger()` before doing anything else:

```
protected override void Roger()
{
    base.Roger();
    Console.Write("456");
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
protected override void Roger()
{
    Console.Write("123");
    Console.Write("456");
}
```

[Learn more about `base` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: @CR0N0S.LXIII make sure to understand the difference between `new` and `override` modifiers. Moreover, the code would be easier to understand when `base` if consistently called at beginning/or end of the constructor for a given hierarchy of classes